# To get JSON data from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a subject.js javascript file in which json data is stored:

Subject.js
Example:

```
Teacher = {
    "Eng" : "English",
    "Math" : "Maths",
    "Sci" : "Science",
    "SST" : "Social Studies",
    "Hin" : "Hindi"
};
```

I want to read json data from this js file into another js file.

But I  learnt that  `$.getJSON('filename.json', function(data) {` is used to get data from json file but my json data is stored in js file.  Can anyone tell me how to get started?  I tried using getJson but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. The file can just be included and use the teacher variable as if you ran the `getJSON` function.
2. The `Teacher =` and semi-colon at the end can be removed (verify it is a correct JSON structure) and save the file as `.json`.  Assuming your server will send a JSON file, this should allow the file to be requested.

Comment: Thanks.If I follow your first point,then do I need to use getJson to read data?

Comment: No ... simply use the variable; i.e. `Teacher.Eng` or `Teacher.Math`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the varibale declaration `"Teacher ="` and your **js** become a **json** content that can be called by `$.getJSON`

Comment: But in mY js file ,i have many variables like teacher.example: marks,percentage etc so removing teacher wont work

Comment: you may strip out those variables declaration and split their contents into several json files.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to include the file with your Teacher definition on the same page as your other JS file.  Then you will have access to the variables defined in Subject.js.  For instance:

```
<script src="Subject.js"></script>
<script>
    console.log(Teacher.Sci)
</script>
```

would output `Science` to the javascript console.

JSON is not its own type in Javascript, it is simply a certain syntax for defining plain-old Javascript objects.  JSON stands for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation.  This is the JSON part of your example:

```
{
    "Eng" : "English",
    "Math" : "Maths",
    "Sci" : "Science",
    "SST" : "Social Studies",
    "Hin" : "Hindi"
}
```

So when you set a variable equal to a JSON block as in your example, you are creating an object with those properties.  As such, you can simply treat that JSON object like any other javascript object.  The code you provided is the same as the following:

```
Teacher = new Object();
Teacher.Eng = "English";
Teacher.Math = "Maths";
Teacher.Sci = "Science";
Teacher.SST = "Social Studies";
Teacher.Hin = "Hindi";
```

`$.getJSON`, on the other hand, is used for converting a text file (or file output) in JSON notation into a javascript object, but that is not necessary in this case, as your JSON object is already created within the javascript code.